# Can't find pub/cache folder in %LOCALAPPDATA%

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make pub an environment variable. The dart.dev says it must be in user/AppData/roaming folder named as pub I looked in roaming, local and locallow folders but there is not such a directory. The dart itself is installed with flutter sdk I looked in the folder too there is a folder named bup-cache but it does not have a pub.bat or pub.exe file as far as I saw.
Pub get itself works fine when i use it with flutter on VSC IDE  but I can not locate the folder to make it environment variable.
Can you guys help me find The pub folder?
Thanks in advance
and be cool I'm a newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go inside of this folder on Windows:

C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache

Maybe you cleared the cache and that's why you cant find it

Comment: Well now it's not there but pub get works how to get it back or get it

Comment: Try the command 'dart pub cache repair'

Comment: If you add executables like the rename package for example the cache folder will also get created again

Comment: It works fine now and dart pub cache repair is the answer

Answer (score 0):

well i got it sorted out in a way the folder was not there and i needed it to use stagehand.
I simply ran a code in CMD or whatever shell which let to solution it was:
`dart pub global activate stagehand`